# RSS pubDate an Hour behind when parsed through PHP. Daylight Savings Time?

Tags: php, date, rss, dst, pubdate

This is probably a super simple question - but I'm a little boggled.

We're pulling in an RSS feed to list events on our site - but ever since DST they've been showing up as an hour behind (on the main, separate site they're showing up just fine).

For simplicity's sake, lets whittle it down to this:

```
$eventTime = "Thu, 05 Dec 2013 10:00:00 -0400";
$tz = date_default_timezone_get();

echo $tz. "<br />";
echo "Event Time: " .date('n/j/y g:ia O', strtotime($eventTime));
```

Which returns:

```
America/New_York 
Event Time: 12/5/13 9:00am -0500
```

After reading and reading and reading - I think it's safe to deduce that the timezone of the site pumping out the feed and our server are operating on different timezones.  The only solutions I've been able to find is to set OUR timezone via date_Default_timezone_set() from New York to whatever the -0400 timezone is (...I...for the life of me can't figure out what it is) - but since we were fine BEFORE DST, wouldn't that mean that we have to readjust our timezone every time DST comes and goes?

Anyone have any advice or have I arrived at the conclusion to this issue myself?

Comment: `Thu, 05 Dec 2013 10:00:00 -0400` is same as your `12/5/13 9:00am -0500`. `strtotime()` converts formated datetime string (with timezone or not) into timestamp; then you use `date()` function to format this timestamp back to your format and timezone. This is how it works and should work.

Comment: Ack. @Glavić You're right!  The weird thing is - is that, that event was listed on the main site as being at 10am - but shows up when parsed by my feed as 9AM.  That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Site is probably in timezone UTC-5, that's why it prints out 9AM. But since RSS feed has datetime with timezone offset, i would say this is more correct, because you don't know in which timezone site is...

Comment: @Glavić - well the time on the SITE of the event is correct; it's just when I pull the info onto other pages via RSS OFF the main site (we run the main site but it lives on it's own server) the time is an hour off. So I guess the solution is to set the timezone along with my SimpleXML code when pulling the RSS Information? Problem is...I don't even know what timezone it'd be to offset the hour and again, wouldn't we be in the same boat come daylight savings time again in the Spring?